# ASP.NET 5 vNext Forms Having Anti Forgery Tokens Added

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm experiencing an issue where a simple `form` tag is having an `action` and `method` attribute added to it. Also added are some hidden input fields for what I am guessing is anti-forgery.

Here is the html I'm adding in the Razor View:

```
<form>test</form>
```

And here's what's being rendered:

```
<form action="/company/adduser" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    test
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8KMbFT4ebnROrEREXkL-MYlPSgL0ISe6_sqTJXc982ocoWgKH1v_yCV2_5Qa9h8AmVFaNk0i0Wpa6gQlhWY-PHkZ929_Tkv1B-lCR7-aLyd53L2448CLQNtakb-UHQmLgPGCiQF0dj4jij9lc_sS7jRPjcGFnNjxdT_wobz-CsU3NvR-fm-a9r0MnqhflgwLLw">
</form>
```

It's causing major issues since I'm only using asp.net MVC to serve up HTML and using AngularJS on the client. The `action` methods is causing issues with angular when trying to use `ng-submit`.

Does anyone know:

1. Is MVC somehow automatically adding anti-forgery tokens?
2. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, that's just a bug in the Form tag helper. It will be fixed.

You can exclude Form (or any element) from taghelper processing by adding a ! as in `<!form></!form>`

Comment: Just FYI...this bug was fixed few days back https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/e68986346176105db379da023eac245e0ad912bb

Comment: Scott, why not just let devs opt-in instead of having to opt-out for these new features? like the Rob said, many of us are using MVC to serve up HTML and using Angular or other JS frameworks for client-side development

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that Microsoft added new TagHelpers and one of them is `<form>`. It seems to be adding all that extra "stuff".

**Edit and better fix:**

I ended up configuring TagHelpers to have a prefix. In my `_GlobalImport.cshtml` I added:

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@tagHelperPrefix "asp:"
```

This allowed me to add "asp:" in front of any TagHelpers I did want to render. This also prevented the `<form>` tags from being rendered by the TagHelper.

**I was notified by Damien Edwards on the ASP.NET team at Microsoft that the issue with the form tag is a bug and will be fixed. I still thought this information would be helpful in the meantime.**

You can also prevent a TagHelper from rendering by adding a `!` in front like so: `<!form></!form>`

Comment: Just FYI...this bug was fixed few days back https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/e68986346176105db379da023eac245e0ad912bb

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm still using beta4, once the next version is pushed to nuget I imagine none of this will be necessary.